# Preencher campo text-area enquanto é digitado informação no input

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um **text-area** e um **input**, queria que ao digitar alguma informação no **input** ele já preenche no **text-area**. Tentei o evento **onchange**, mas pelo que eu observei ele só é disparado quando sai do campo, tem algum evento do input que faça isso?

```
<input onchange="FuncaoTeste();" type="text" class="form-control" id="iptDetalhes">
```

Comment: pode usar o `onkeyup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas complementando a resposta do Marcos ,o evento [onChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) só vai refletir o valor digitado no `input` quando o mesmo receber o evento de **blur**, ou seja, perder o foco, já com eventos de teclado como [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event),  ou [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/input) no momento que for digitado algo no input, estes valores serão repassados automaticamente para o `textarea`:

```js
let valor = document.getElementById('iptDetalhes');

valor.addEventListener('input', () => document.getElementById('textarea').textContent = valor.value)
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="iptDetalhes"> <br><br>
<textarea id="textarea" cols="22"></textarea>
```

Comment: Entendi, deu certo com o evento oninput. Valeu

Answer (score 5):

Fica aqui um exemplo com o `onkeyup` (como disse o @leonardo-getulio):

HTML

```
<textarea id="iptDetalhesCopia"></textarea>
<input onkeyup="FuncaoTeste( this.value )" type="text" class="form-control" id="iptDetalhes" placeholder="Digite aqui">
```

JS

```
function FuncaoTeste( e ) {
    document.getElementById( 'iptDetalhesCopia' ).value = e;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xtkfrbj2/