# Evento de click à tag tr de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo uma tabela `HTML` que preencho com dados que possuo em um banco de dados.

Cada *tag* `tr` da minha *table* representa um cliente, desconsiderando a *tag* `tr` do cabeçalho.

Gostaria de adicionar um evento de *click* às tags `tr`, como se estivessem selecionando um cliente.

Tabela HTML :

```html
<table id="modelTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Id User</th>
        <th>UserEmail</th>
        <th>CodeCustomer</th>
        <th>DateCreation</th>
        <th>DateContract</th>
        <th>Condition</th>
        </tr>                          
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Estou tentando desta forma (javaScript) :

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("tr").addEventListener('click', function () {
      console.log("clique");
});
```

Error :

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   document.getElementsByTagName(...).addEventListener is not a function
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.

Devo estar deixando algo passar, contudo já gastei algum tempo procurando, gostaria que alguém pudesse me apontar onde estou errando.

Comment: Não vai dar certo mesmo quando faz isto **document.getElementsByTagName("tr")** é retornando uma `nodelist` ou seja uma array com todas os elementos **`tr`** do documento, mesmo que só tenha uma. Vc prercisa acessar por um índice assim por exemplo **[0]**

Comment: @LeAndrade Obrigado pelo comentario. Sua sugestão funcionou em partes, pois só esta funcionando para a tag tr de índice 0. Quando eu adiciono por exemplo o índice 1 aparece este erro : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Sim, pq só tem uma **tr**.

Comment: @ LeAndrade Mas não teria uma forma de adicionar o evento de click às tags tr que são adicionadas a tabela (createElement("tr")) ?

Comment: Sim, claro, mas, aí é outro esquema, vc vai ter que fazer um **for()** percorrendo todo documento e acessando os índices das trs pelo for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modelTable > tbody > tr").on('click', function() {
        console.log("clique");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="modelTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Id User</th>
    <th>UserEmail</th>
    <th>CodeCustomer</th>
    <th>DateCreation</th>
    <th>DateContract</th>
    <th>Condition</th>
    </tr>                          
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>teste</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>;
```

Comment: @Levi poderia ter especificado nas tags que tbm poderiam utilizar jquery, e só para deixar registrado que este método **delegate()** está **`deprecated`** conforme a documentação: https://api.jquery.com/Delegate/

Comment: @LeAndrade obrigado pelo aviso. Correção já foi feita.

Comment: Desnecessário esses `>`, mas.... :D

Answer (score 3):

O método `getElementsByTagName` da Documentação de interface retorna um `HTMLCollection` e não um `HTMLAnchorElement`). Acho que isso pode te interessar [Qual a diferença de NodeList para HTMLCollection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17237/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-nodelist-para-htmlcollection)

Uma forma de contornar isso é trocar o `getElementsByTagName` por `querySelector` ou `querySelectorAll` e fazer um `forEach()` para pegar só a `tr` clicada

Aqui tem um exemplo:

```js
const tr = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

function teste() {
 console.log('oi');
}

tr.forEach( function (e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', teste)
})
```

```html
<table id="modelTable">
    <thead style="background: silver">
        <tr>
            <th>Id User</th>
            <th>UserEmail</th>
            <th>CodeCustomer</th>
            <th>DateCreation</th>
            <th>DateContract</th>
            <th>Condition</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Id User</th>
            <th>UserEmail</th>
            <th>CodeCustomer</th>
            <th>DateCreation</th>
            <th>DateContract</th>
            <th>Condition</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Id User</th>
            <th>UserEmail</th>
            <th>CodeCustomer</th>
            <th>DateCreation</th>
            <th>DateContract</th>
            <th>Condition</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "_desconsiderando a tag tr do cabeçalho_"...

Comment: É só alterar para `document.querySelectorAll('#modelTable tbody tr')`.

Comment: @Sam obrigado pela observação! Acabei de editar. Hhaha foi tipo isso que fiz, usei o tbody no seletor :D

Comment: É isso aí man, +1

Comment: @LeAndrade  é impressionante como 20% do JS resolve 80% dos problemas rss. JS é muito massa, hj mesmo eu tava vendo essas resposta sua https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/410012/preencher-campo-text-area-enquanto-%c3%a9-digitado-informa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-input/410021#410021 eu não conhecia o `.textContent` achei bem massa a forma como vc fez, e a resposta do outro cara tb achei legal. Por isso escuto falar que jQuery vai morrer. Tmj

Comment: Legal Hugo, obrigado! Realmente apesar de ser muito bom, está cada vez mais raro achar jQuery por aí.

Comment: Acho mt difícil o jQuery morrer. Vc carrega apenas 80KB de código que facilita bastante a manipulação de elementos no JS. Se vai morrer um dia, pode até ser, mas acho que ainda tá longe disso acontecer.